# href cell in a data grid Dojo

Tags: datagrid, cell, dojo, dojox.grid

i cant find how put a cell with an href in a dojo toolkit datagrid, the version od dojo  that am using is 1.6 
this is my table

```
  <table id="billsGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-props="escapeHTMLInData:false">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="name" width="auto">name</th>
                <th field="description" width="auto">Description</th>
                <th field="activity" width="auto">activity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

am getting the data with Json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formatter function to format a cell. For example, you can declare a JavaScript object that contains all the formatting function.

```
var myFormatters = {
   formatLink : function(value, index) {
        return "<a href='#'>" + value + "</a>";
   }
};
```

Then in the grid,

```
<table id="billsGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-props="escapeHTMLInData:false" formatterScope="myFormatters"  >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th formatter="formatLink" field="name" width="auto">name</th>
            <th field="description" width="auto">Description</th>
            <th field="activity" width="auto">activity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

You don't need to create a scope object for the formatters, then this formatting functions should be in the global scope and then you can omit the `formatterScope` attribute in the grid.

Comment: I got another question, how can get a parameter from the url, i mean if have page1.html?id=12345 , i need to get the id from the url, i know that in Jquery is $.url.param("id"); but in Dojo how is?

Comment: You need to get the url first using `window.location.href`, then extract the query portion after the `?`. After you get the query string, like `id=12345&name=alex`, you can use `dojo.queryToObject` to convert it to a JSON object `{id:'12345', name:'alex'}`

Answer (score 1):

dojo grid is escaping html tags by default for security reasons, you can simply enable html tags doing this:

```
<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" escapeHTMLInData="false" ...>
```

or this if your grid is added programatically

```
escapeHTMLInData: false
```

more info here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html